# What is this Time Format 1381039499

Tags: time

could someone explain me what is this Time Format?

1381039499

I do not know how should I have to change it to normal Time format

Comment: What you probably see is the unix timestamp. Essentially, it is the number of seconds passed since 1 January 1970. It is widely used in unix like operating systems as a measurement of time. You can convert it to any format you'd like, but it is a perfectly valid time format. Not very human readable though.

Comment: I have this time format in my database. the data that extract from API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this site](http://www.epochconverter.com/), that is the [Unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) for:

> Sun, 06 Oct 2013 06:04:59 GMT.

Most programming languages have a function to convert to/from Unix timestamps, but the correct way to do this will obviously vary between them.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it's the Unix Epoc, defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970.